# (HIVE) how to WHERE filter by date, last 30 days?

Tags: sql, hive, where-clause

wondering how this is supposed to work, I'm new to HIVE.

I have several date_time columns in the data_Type format = timestamp.

how can I filter generically by t-xdays?

```html
select *
from table
where DateCol >= current_date - 30
```

how to get this to work in HIVE?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using `interval`-

```
select *
from table
where DateCol >= current_date() - interval '30' day
```

You can also use `datediff` -

```
select *
from table
where datediff (DateCol,current_date()) >=30
```

Comment: so no need to convert to/from UNIXtime?

Comment: `DateCol` - is it timestamp or unixdatetimne format?

Comment: Then not needed  :) because you are comparing timestamp to timestamp